# What the difference between [FromRoute] and [FromBody] in a Web API?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

What the difference between `[FromRoute]` and `[FromBody]` in a Web API?

```
[Route("api/Settings")]
public class BandwidthController : Controller
{
    // GET: api/Settings
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Setting> GetSettings()
    {
        return _settingRespository.GetAllSettings();
    }

    // GET: api/Settings/1
    [HttpGet("{facilityId}", Name = "GetTotalBandwidth")]
    public IActionResult GetTotalBandwidth([FromRoute] int facilityId)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return HttpBadRequest(ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

Also for `PUT`:

```
// PUT: api/Setting/163/10
[HttpPut]
public void UpdateBandwidthChangeHangup([FromRoute] int facilityId, int bandwidthChange)
{
    _settingRespository.UpdateBandwidthHangup(facilityId, bandwidthChange);
}
```

Can I use `[FromBody]`?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

> #### [FromBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.frombodyattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.0)
>
> Specifies that a parameter or property should be bound using the request body.

When you use `FromBody` attribute you are specifying that the data is coming from the body of the request body and not from the request URL/URI. You cannot use this attribute with `HttpGet` requests, only with PUT,POST,and Delete requests. Also you can only use one `FromBody` attribute tag per action method in Web API (if this has changed in mvc core I could not find anything to support that).

> #### [FromRouteAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromrouteattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.0)
>
> Summary: Specifies that a parameter or property should be bound using route-data from the current request.

Essentially it `FromRoute` will look at your route parameters and extract / bind the data based on that. As the route, when called externally, is usually based on the URL. In previous version(s) of web api this is comparable to `FromUri`.

```
[HttpGet("{facilityId}", Name = "GetTotalBandwidth")]
public IActionResult GetTotalBandwidth([FromRoute] int facilityId)
```

So this would try to bind `facilityId` based on the route parameter with the same name.

```
Complete route definition: /api/Settings/GetTotalBandwidth/{facilityId}
Complete received url: /api/Settings/GetTotalBandwidth/100
```

---

#### Edit

Based on your last question, here is the corresponding code assuming you want 163 to be bound to facilityId and 10 to bandwidthChange parameters.

```
// PUT: api/Setting/163/10

[HttpPut("{facilityId}/{bandwidthChange}")] // constructor takes a template as parameter
public void UpdateBandwidthChangeHangup([FromRoute] int facilityId, [FromRoute] int bandwidthChange) // use multiple FromRoute attributes, one for each parameter you are expecting to be bound from the routing data
{
    _settingRespository.UpdateBandwidthHangup(facilityId, bandwidthChange);
}
```

If you had a complex object in one of the parameters and you wanted to send this as the body of the Http Request then you could use `FromBody` instead of `FromRoute` on that parameter. Here is an example taken from the [Building Your First Web API with ASP.NET Core MVC](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-web-api.html)

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public IActionResult Update([FromRoute] string id, [FromBody] TodoItem item);
```

There are also other options in MVC Core like `FromHeader` and `FromForm` and `FromQuery`.

Comment: `FromRoute` is from asp.net-core-1.0, I don't know how to use it.

Comment: @Love - Ah, thanks. I will look one more time with that context. The answer to your last question though is No because both of those actions are HttpGet. The body of the request will only contain something when used with HttpPut, HttpDelete, or HttpPost.

Comment: Yes, when you find it. Please update your answer. Better have an example.

Comment: The difficult thing for me is `PUT` and `POST`.  I am not sure how to deal with it? Say we have an example. `// PUT: api/Setting/163/10
        [HttpPut]
        public void UpdateBandwidthChangeHangup([FromRoute] int facilityId,int bandwidthChange)
        {
            _settingRespository.UpdateBandwidthHangup(facilityId,bandwidthChange);
        }`. Is that okay? I updated my question.

Comment: Thank you. In my code, `api/Setting` was generated by VS automatically. So actually it should match the maproute? In my case:  `routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action}/{facilityId?}");`. It should be `api/controllername`?

Comment: @Love - Because you are using the [RouteAttribute](https://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/1.0.0-rc1/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNet/Mvc/RouteAttribute/index.html?highlight=routeattribute) I used that to build up the Url instead of the default `ControllerName`. If you remove the RouteAttribute then I believe it should be based on what you have there, `api/ControllerName`

Comment: Can I use HttpPost insted of HttpPut => [HttpPut("{facilityId}/{bandwidthChange}")]

Answer (score 5):

### Confusion with [FromRoute] versus [FromBody]

Microsoft has done a good job with ASP.NET trying to connect Internet technology into their frameworks and systems. But in the process they often ***confuse developers*** by trying to patch their technology solutions on top of what are very simple HTTP and HTML technologies. People walk away assuming their solutions represent how the World Wide Web works...when it simply does not. Routing URL solutions in both their .NET Framework and Core version of ASP.NET are still confusing to many.

Hopefully this helps...

When you create a basic "route" in ASP.NET Core, **you are binding your your browser's *URL Address Path* to a specific *Controller Class and its child Method()* inside a ASP.NET compiled application**. Binding means that *Middleware*, they designed, sniffs the URL address and tries to take it apart and then match the pieces to code inside your website.

Special Controller-ControllerBase classes handle this process inside ASP.NET using Conventional Routing Templates and Routing Attributes mapped to child Methods inside your classes. That includes the *parameters* of those methods. This then "routes" all URL browser address path requests to a specific set of code inside your web application in ASP.NET.

Unfortunately, there are too many ways to configure this binding. In the past, it was a bunch of random combinations of Route Templates to controllers & methods, with additional code to map a url to parameters. But that was not always clear for things like *query strings*. ASP.NET Core has tried to clean up that mess with these new Attribute Routing decorations like [FromRoute], etc.

So how do they work?

```
[Route("/mypath/{myid}")]
public string MyMethod(int myid){...}

The above matches this browser URL address on the Web:
http://example.com/mypath/5
```

In its simplest form, ASP.NET MVC or WebAPI uses a "route" text string to map a specific method parameter name to a matching URL path. `[FromRoute]` helps by binding explicitly a methods parameter name to a matching part of the URL in `{}`:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]// "/api/test"
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("{facilityId}")]// "/api/test/26"
    public IActionResult GetTotalBandwidth([FromRoute] int facilityId)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The `[FromRoute]` attribute decoration, however, is optional as Middleware in ASP.NET by default tries to map that for you out of the box. If you leave `[FromRoute]` off, it will try and map your parameter name to the route template name inside `{}`, as so:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]// "/api/test"
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("{facilityId}")]// "/api/test/26"
    public IActionResult GetTotalBandwidth(int facilityId)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

`[FromQuery]`, however, only binds to Querystring URL parameters, which lie outside the URL route, according to Microsoft. But I have always considered them as part of the URL. In past iterations of ASP.NET this was left out so people had to fudge a way to grab these values inside the method using `Request.QueryString`. So this new feature fixes this issue:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]// "/api/test"
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("{facilityId}")]// "/api/test/26?num=5"
    public IActionResult GetTotalBandwidth(int facilityId,[FromQuery] int num)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

### [FromBody] is Completely Different!

Capturing data from a `POST` has always been tricky. ASP.NET helps solve that by allowing the route URL mapping system to function as normal in listening for the POST and URL request, but using an additional method parameter attribute system to bind to that data coming in using `[FromBody]`. In the case of POST HTTP VERB types, POST is unique, as a POST has nothing to do with URL mapping. But in this case ASP.NET is using the attribute parameter binding system to grab that form field data for you.

Let's first see how `POST` *form fields* work.

When you send HTML form data using a "method=post" like so:

```
<!doctype html>
<html xml:lang="en-us" lang="en-us">
<head></head>
<body>

<form id="f1" name="f1" method="post" action="">
  <input type="text" id="field1" name="field1" size="20" value="" />
  <button id="mybutton" name="mybutton" value="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

...that sends the form field data packaged inside the "body" of the Request like so as a POST:

```
HTTP HEADER
Content-Type: text/html
Last-Modified: Fri, 27 Jan 2023 17:45:32 GMT

HTTP BODY
field1=hello&mybutton=submit
```

Notice the form field POST data is inside a special "body" or payload section of the request post (`field1=hello&mybutton=submit`). To get that data, you need to use `[FromForm]`(for traditional name-value form POST data) or `[FromBody]` (special JavaScript JSON Post data only) in ASP.NET parameter decorations, like so:

```
// Note: In the example below, "field1" only captures one field.

[Route("api/[controller]")]// "/api/test"
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]// "/api/test"
    public string MyPostMethod([FromForm] string field1)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

`[FromForm]` captures regular HTML POST form fields (one field or all fields) as *name-value* pairs in the WebAPI POST endpoint.

`[FromBody]` captures the form fields but only as JSON data, requiring an additional content-type of 'application/json' added to the POST request sent to the server. **Because HTML Forms cannot do that, you have to use JavaScript when using `[FromBody]`.**

So, **`[FromBody]` is almost always used with a POST and has nothing to do with binding a Route Template as part of the URL** like [FromRoute] or [FromQuery] might do, but simply captures any POST data typically found inside a POST request form submission sent inside the Http Request package.

Hope that helps!

Comment: One of the best answers I've read on SO - thanks for the explanation.