# How to query bind parameter?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-apicontroller

I'm trying to query bind the parameter `id`. It keeps coming through as `0`. `s2` has a value when supplied:

id=0, s=null
http://localhost/api/values/123

id=0, s2=true
http://localhost/api/values/123?s2=true

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("sub/{id?}")] 
    public string Get([FromQuery]int id, string s2)
    {
        return "value";
    }
```

Why isn't `id` being captured?

Comment: Take off `[FromQuery]`. You're explicitly stating it should come from the query string, but it doesn't.

Comment: @KirkLarkin: Excellent. Thanks! When is `[FromQuery]` used?

Comment: It's for if you want to be more exact - The binding is pretty smart and checks multiple sources (e.g. route, query string, body). You can use these attributes ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding#customize-model-binding-behavior-with-attributes)) if you want to be more explicit and exact. e.g [FromQuery] says *only* bind if the parameter is in the query-string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to use FromRoute for an Id as it is coming via route and change Http Get as well, it is not aligned with what you passing in url

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet()] 
    public string Get([FromRoute]int id, [FromQuery]string s2)
    {
        return "value";
    }
}
```

Comment: I can see your code does work. Once I remove `[FromQuery]` in the OP, it also works. What's the difference?

Comment: this link will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37276932/what-the-difference-between-fromroute-and-frombody-in-web-api

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("sub/{id?}")] 
    public string Get(int? id, string s2)
    {
        return "value";
    }
}
```