# Why would I use the route and body in a HttpPut call?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm refactoring an endpoint and have come across this method:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Foo>> Put([FromRoute]int fooId, [FromBody]Foo model)
{
   ...
   return Ok(data);
}
```

I'm trying to understand why they would use both the `[FromRoute]` and the `[FromBody]`. Is this bad practice or is this actually helpful in some way (i.e. security reasons)? The Id is already being passed in the model so I assume this is bad practice.

Comment: read from this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37276932/what-the-difference-between-fromroute-and-frombody-in-web-api

Comment: I'll express my opinion - url defines what object need to be created and body defines what that object should contain... I see no problems that "model" contains some of the same information that identifies the object in url - validating that both match or discarding model's data is you call.

Comment: It is bad practice to pass the ID in the model, not the other way around. The ID of the resource being modified should be part of the URL (i.e. FromRoute), while the actual data that is allowed to be changed (i.e. *not* the ID), comes in the request body. Any attempt to change the ID in the URL actually then maps to an entirely different resource, which based on resource-level permissions that are applied, can be blocked or allowed accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is common practice.

`FromRoute` is from the URL. You need something to identify the resource. `FromBody` is the request body and you need the resource values themselves.

It is not common to trust or use the request body for the ID of the resource.

Comment: "It is not common to trust the request body for the ID of the resource" I don't see the difference. If the attacker knows how to put the ID in the body, they know how to put it in the URL. I find it a common and weird practice

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: The core difference is that changing the ID in the URL makes it a request *to an entirely different resource*. Whereas passing it in the body, makes no such distinction. With the URL, resource-level permissions can be easily applied to protect objects with different IDs, whereas it is far more difficult, if not totally impractical to do the same based on a particular post body.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto there is no security concerns here... just REST PUT request defines resource location in the url - so information in the model is secondary and not necessary required to match the resource location (i.e. model may have defaults for location)